# Get a list of installed bibliography styles with kpsewhich?

Tags: kpsewhich

Is there a way to call kpsewhich that will list all the installed bibliography styles?

I know I can run:

```
kpsewhich -show-path bst
```

to see the paths that are searched, but the format of the output is a colon separated list that things that have !! in them, and otherwise don't appear to be paths or they don't exist on my computer.

Thanks,

Comment: the `!!` tells the search library not to search the filesystem but to consult the pre-computed ls-R files that are made when you run `texhash` or equivalent command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but lists all directories in the expansion of `BSTINPUTS` (code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/918898/923955).

Make a script file containing

```bash
for i in $(echo `kpsewhich -expand-path '$BSTINPUTS'` | tr ":" "\n")
do
 ls $i/*.bst
done
```

Running `bash` over this will show

```
ls: ./*.bst: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst/*.bst: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst/local/*.bst: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/*.bst: No such file or directory
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/aastex/aasjournal.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abntex2/abntex2-alf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abntex2/abntex2-num.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/aabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/aalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/anotit.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/aplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/aunsnot.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/abstyles/aunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/achemso/achemso.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/achemso/biochem.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/acmart/ACM-Reference-Format.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/adfathesis/adfathesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/adrconv/adrbirthday.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/adrconv/adrconv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/adrconv/adrfax.bst
[...many other lines...]
```

Answer (score 2):

For bst in the directories that have been indexed by ls-r files at least, you can use

```
grep '[.]bst' `kpsewhich --all ls-R`
```

which on my texlive 2018 installation gives 419 files:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aasjournal.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abntex2-alf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abntex2-num.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:anotit.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aunsnot.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:achemso.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:biochem.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ACM-Reference-Format.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:adfathesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:adrbirthday.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:adrconv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:adrfax.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:thesnumb.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agu.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agu04.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agufull.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agufull04.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aiaa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aichej.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ajl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ametsoc2014.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsra.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsrn.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsrs.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsru.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:amsry.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aomalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aomplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apacann.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apacannx.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apacite.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apacitex.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike-german.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:asaetr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ascelike.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbr3.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbr3-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbr3-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbrv-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bababbrv-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babalpha-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babalpha-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babamspl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplai3.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplai3-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplai3-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplain-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babplain-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babunsrt-fl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:babunsrt-lf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:acm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ieeetr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:siam.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bath.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bathx.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aaai-named.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abstract.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:annotate.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:annotation.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:astron.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:authordate1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:authordate2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:authordate3.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:authordate4.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bbs.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bibtoref.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cbe.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chicagoa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:humanbio.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:humannat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:is-abbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:is-alpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:is-plain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:is-unsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jas99.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jbact.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jmb.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jtb.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jthcarsu.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:named.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:namunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:newapa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phaip.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phapalik.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phcpc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phiaea.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phjcp.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phnf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phnflet.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phpf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phppcf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phreport.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phrmp.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainyr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:refer.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bjnano.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:besjournals.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bestpapers.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bestpapers-export.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bgteuabbr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bgteuabbr2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bgteupln.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bgteupln2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bgteupln3.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:expcites.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:expkeys.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:export.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrv-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvnat-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alpha-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ieeetr-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainnat-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:siam-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrt-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrtnat-fr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvhtml.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alphahtml.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alphahtmldate.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alphahtmldater.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainhtml.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainhtmldate.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainhtmldater.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrthtml.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:biblatex.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:biolett.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:bookdb.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cascadilla.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cell.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ChemCommun.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ChemEurJ.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:InorgChem.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:JAmChemSoc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:JAmChemSoc_all.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jcc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jpc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:pccp.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:revcompchem.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chetref.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chicago.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chicago-annote.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chscite.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cjebibstyle.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cmpj.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvcnb.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cc2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:newapave.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cont-ab.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cont-au.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cont-no.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cont-ti.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cqunumerical.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:databib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvdin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alphadin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:natdin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plaindin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrtdin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dinat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:address.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:address-html.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:address-ldif.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:address-vcard.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:birthday.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:email.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:email-html.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:letter.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:phone.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dk-abbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dk-alpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dk-apali.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dk-plain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dk-unsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dlfltxbbibtex.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dcbib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aer.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aertt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agecon.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ajae.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apecon.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cje.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ecca.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ecta.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:erae.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ier.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:itaxpf.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jae.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jpe.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jss2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:oega.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:regstud.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:tandfx.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:worlddev.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:elsarticle-harv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:elsarticle-num.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:elsarticle-num-names.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:fbs.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:fcavtex.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:figbib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:figbib1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:finplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:francais.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:francaissc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:achicago.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gatech-thesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gatech-thesis-losa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gbt7714-plain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gbt7714-unsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gerabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:geralpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gerapali.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gerplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gerunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:glsplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:glsshort.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2003.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2003s.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008l.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008ls.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008n.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008ns.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost2008s.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost780.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:gost780s.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2003.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2003s.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008l.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008ls.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008n.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008ns.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ugost2008s.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agsm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:dcu.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jmr.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jphysicsB.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:kluwer.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:nederlands.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:hc-de.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:hc-en.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:hithesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:hustthesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ieeepes.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtran.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranN.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranS.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranSA.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranSN.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ijmart.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ijqc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:imac.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:xagsm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:xplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:inlinebib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:iopart-num.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jneurosci.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jox.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jurabib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jureco.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jurunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jurarsp.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:klunamed.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:klunum.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ksfh_nat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:langsci-unified.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:lion-msc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:listbib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:lni.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:lnig.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrevM.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrmpM.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranM.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranMN.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mnras.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mslapa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mbplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mbunsrtdin.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chronological.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:munich.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:nar.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrtnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:naturemag.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:nddiss2e.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chronoplainnm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainnm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrtnm.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:noTeX.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:opcit.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:perception.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:acm-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:asa-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:chicago-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ieeetr-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain-fa-inLTR.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain-fa-inLTR-beamer.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainnat-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrt-fa.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:naturemagdoi.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:pnas2009.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:papalike.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:psuthesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:resphilosophica.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aipauth4-1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:aipnum4-1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrev4-1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrmp4-1.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrev.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apsrmp.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:angew.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:rsc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sageep.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sapthesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:savetrees.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:seuthesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:seuthesix.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:rusnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrv-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alpha-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:apalike-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:frplainnat-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plain-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainnat-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:siam-letters.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:spiebib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:usmeg-a.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:usmeg-n.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ussagus.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sweabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:swealpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sweplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sweplnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:sweunsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:texsis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:thuthesis-author-year.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:thuthesis-numeric.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:tufte.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:ltugbib.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:udesoftec.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:uestcthesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:UNAMThesis.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:upmplainnat.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:abbrvurl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alphaurl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainurl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrturl.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:vak.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:vancouver.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:pst-doc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:biblist.bst-dist
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtran.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtran.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainDemo.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainDemo.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranN.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:IEEEtranSN.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:h-physrev.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:easy.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainDemo.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:alpha2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:easy.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainDemo.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:plainDemo.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:en-mtc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:fr-mtc.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mn2e.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unified.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:zharticle.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:cqunumerical.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:agufull08.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:unsrtabbrv3.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:mybibstyle.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:CUEDbiblio.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:PhDbiblio-bold.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:PhDbiblio-case.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:PhDbiblio-url.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:PhDbiblio-url2.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:GBTbibsty.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:tex-live.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jabbrv.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jalpha.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jipsj.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jname.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jorsj.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:jplain.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:junsrt.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:tieice.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:tipsj.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R:francais.bst
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the same result. Interestingly, the method above this one returns 754 styles.